# Is there a way to uninstall all of VS2008 easily or do I really have to hunt each component down 1-by-1 in Installed Programs?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, uninstall

Is there a way to uninstall all of VS2008 easily or do I really have to hunt each component down 1-by-1 in Installed Programs?

[image]

This is ridiculous...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the *main* uninstaller for Visual Studio, it may give you a dialog in which you can select components to be removed.

If not, then you will have to remove components yourself.

Always use the main uninstaller first to see what that will get rid of.